# Embedded and email signing combined

Tags: docusignapi

I have a situation where I want to have a technician sign documents in a single envelope via an embedded environment and then have our customers sign via an email.  So our situation would be something like this:

1. Technician (embedded)
2. Customer (email)
3. Technician (embedded)
4. Customer (email)
5. Technician(embedded)
6. Customer (email)

I'm accomplishing this by not adding the clientuserid (or actually setting it to blank) to the customer recipient.

The problem I'm having is I get through steps 1 to 3 fine, but the second email to the customer never arrives.

Have you had an issue like this?

Thanks,
Jim

Here is an example of my JSON that is posted to create the envelope:

```
{
"EmailSubject": "John Smith - Ticket: 13106923 / branch: 104",
"EmailBlurb": "",
"Status": "Sent",
"CompositeTemplates": [{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "203bac25-eab0-4990-bcfb-b59131ed187b",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 1
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "",
                        "TabLabel": "ClaimNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "13106923",
                        "TabLabel": "TicketNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxxx Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullAddress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxx-661-6273",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerPhone1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerBillToAddress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": ", ",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerBillToCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "02/20/2019",
                        "TabLabel": "TicketStartDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "02/20/2019",
                        "TabLabel": "TicketEndDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx STREET",
                        "TabLabel": "XXAddress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "XXCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "(xxx) 555-1212",
                        "TabLabel": "XXPhoneNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "42 4657345",
                        "TabLabel": "XXFederalNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "03/11/2019",
                        "TabLabel": "CurrentDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "4237",
                        "TabLabel": "TechNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "4237",
                        "TabLabel": "TechNumber-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "JIM HUNT",
                        "TabLabel": "TechFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "JIM HUNT",
                        "TabLabel": "TechFullName-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "104",
                        "TabLabel": "BranchNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton",
                        "TabLabel": "Location"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "3",
                "RecipientId": "3",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["3"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "4",
                "RecipientId": "4",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["4"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "5",
                "RecipientId": "5",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["5"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "6",
                "RecipientId": "6",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["6"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": [{
                "Email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.COM",
                "Name": "CC - John Hunt",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1001",
                "RoutingOrder": "5"
            },
            {
                "Email": "YYYYYYYY@GMAIL.COM",
                "Name": "CC - Boss",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1002",
                "RoutingOrder": "5"
            },
            {
                "Email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.COM",
                "Name": "CC - John Hunt",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1001",
                "RoutingOrder": "7"
            },
            {
                "Email": "YYYYYYYY@GMAIL.COM",
                "Name": "CC - Boss",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1002",
                "RoutingOrder": "7"
            }]
        },
        "Sequence": "1"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "952a2b19-9657-44ea-854c-2b0fd9d06d79",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 2
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "02/20/2019",
                        "TabLabel": "DateOfLoss"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullAddress"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": null
        },
        "Sequence": "2"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "419aab1a-31c3-4112-b40d-18dd5575b7da",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 3
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "11",
                        "TabLabel": "DayOfMonth"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "March",
                        "TabLabel": "Month"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "19",
                        "TabLabel": "LastTwoOfYear"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerAddress1and2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "JIM HUNT",
                        "TabLabel": "TechFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullAddress"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "xxxx
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullAddress"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": null
        },
        "Sequence": "3"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "ff879c26-ea74-4e4f-b509-9e31d1de9a7a",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 4
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "",
                        "TabLabel": "ClaimNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerAddress1and2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "JIM HUNT",
                        "TabLabel": "TechFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx STREET",
                        "TabLabel": "XXAddress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH 45202",
                        "TabLabel": "XXCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "(xxx) 555-1212",
                        "TabLabel": "XXPhoneNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "42 4657345",
                        "TabLabel": "XXFederalNumber"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": null
        },
        "Sequence": "4"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "72acce02-c897-4b2b-85ce-3094d004f221",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 5
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": null
        },
        "Sequence": "5"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "b8070422-ee4c-4fe3-a657-84616d69c6bd",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 6
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "1",
                "RecipientId": "1",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerAddress1and2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerCityStateZip"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["1"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "2",
                "RecipientId": "2",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["2"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": [{
                "Email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.COM",
                "Name": "CC - John Hunt",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1001",
                "RoutingOrder": "3"
            },
            {
                "Email": "YYYYYYYY@GMAIL.COM",
                "Name": "CC - Boss",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1002",
                "RoutingOrder": "3"
            }]
        },
        "Sequence": "6"
    }]
},
{
    "ServerTemplates": [{
        "IdDecFilterId": 0,
        "IdForTemplate": 0,
        "TemplateId": "a8671e69-4a2d-4785-b69e-6b02165eb615",
        "Name": null,
        "Sequence": 7
    }],
    "InlineTemplates": [{
        "CustomFields": {
            "TextCustomFields": [{
                "Name": "BranchNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "104"
            },
            {
                "Name": "TicketNumber",
                "Required": "false",
                "Show": "false",
                "Value": "13106923"
            }]
        },
        "Recipients": {
            "Signers": [{
                "RoleName": "Technician",
                "Name": "John Hunt",
                "Email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "7",
                "RecipientId": "7",
                "ClientUserId": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [{
                        "Value": "",
                        "TabLabel": "ClaimNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxx STREET",
                        "TabLabel": "XXAddress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH 45202",
                        "TabLabel": "XXCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "(xxx) 555-1212",
                        "TabLabel": "XXPhoneNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "42 4657345",
                        "TabLabel": "XXFederalNumber"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerAddress1and2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Dayton, OH xxxxx",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerCityStateZip"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "JOHN HUNT",
                        "TabLabel": "TechFullName"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "John Smith",
                        "TabLabel": "CustomerFullName-2"
                    }]
                },
                "CustomFields": ["7"]
            },
            {
                "RoleName": "Customer",
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
                "Note": null,
                "RoutingOrder": "8",
                "RecipientId": "8",
                "ClientUserId": "",
                "Tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": []
                },
                "CustomFields": ["8"]
            }],
            "CarbonCopies": [{
                "Email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.COM",
                "Name": "CC - John Hunt",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1001",
                "RoutingOrder": "9"
            },
            {
                "Email": "YYYYYYYY@GMAIL.COM",
                "Name": "CC - Boss",
                "Note": null,
                "RecipientId": "1002",
                "RoutingOrder": "9"
            }]
        },
        "Sequence": "7"
    }]
}]
```

}

Comment: I hope you have tabs for each and every signer else DocuSign will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting "`allowRecipientRecursion`" as "`true`" at envelope definition level parallel to "Status":"Sent". When `allowRecipientRecursion` is set to `true`, this enables the Recursive Recipients feature and allows a recipient to appear more than once in the routing order.

Comment: I tried this and this didn't change anything.  I was able to get through the first three steps, but the second email to the customer just doesn't get delivered.

Comment: Are DS tabs diff for each time flow goes to diif routing order but for same recipient, and you have tabs for each and every signer in an envelope? Can you please check using DS UI where workflow is stuck and if DS is throwing error on the WebUI?

Comment: Hi Amit,  It shows that it is waiting for customers signature on the DS UI.  The tabs are set everywhere that it is needed.

Comment: if DS UI is saying waiting for Signature, then are you sure email did not go to that customer's email? Please check Spam or if you are using GMAIL, and using same email address then it sometimes combine multiple emails with same subject together.